# Merge optional nested array values to create new object

Tags: javascript

There are multiple fields in an object like this.

```
{
  "image-processing": {
    "type": "lib",
    "data": {
      "files": [
        {
          "file": "libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",
          "hash": "62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d"
        },
        {
          "file": "libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",
          "hash": "a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",
          "deps": [
            "npm:gm",
            "npm:mongodb"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "image-processing-2": {
    "type": "lib",
    "data": {
      "files": [
        {
          "file": "libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",
          "hash": "62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d",
          "deps": [
            "npm:gm",
            "npm:faker"
          ]
        },
        {
          "file": "libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",
          "hash": "a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",
          "deps": [
            "npm:gm",
            "npm:mongodb"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I only need the type and the content of `data.files.deps` as value object for the key.
As you can see each file has an optional deps array. All deps values should be merged.

So the result should be:

```
{
    "image-processing": { type: "lib", packages: [ "npm:gm", "npm:mongodb" ] },
    "image-processing-2": { type: "lib", packages: [ "npm:faker", "npm:gm", "npm:mongodb" ] }
}
```

I tried to iterate through the object, but this would overwrite the value instead of adding new package names to the value:

```
const result = {}
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
    result[key].type = value.type
    result[key].packages = value?.data?.files.map(d => d.deps)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map` so that you have a flattened array of dependency strings - and alternate with the empty array so that undefined `.deps` properties don't cause problems.

```js
const data={"image-processing":{type:"lib",data:{files:[{file:"libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",hash:"62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d"},{file:"libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",hash:"a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",deps:["npm:gm","npm:mongodb"]}]}},"image-processing-2":{type:"lib",data:{files:[{file:"libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",hash:"62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d",deps:["npm:gm","npm:faker"]},{file:"libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",hash:"a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",deps:["npm:gm","npm:mongodb"]}]}}};

const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [
    key,
    {
      type: 'lib',
      packages: [...new Set(value.data.files.flatMap(file => file.deps ?? []))]
    }
  ])
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Wow, great. I didn't know about `flatMap`. Is it possible to filter the deps for only `npm:*` values? `[ "npm:gm", "npm:mongodb", "remove-me" ]`

Comment: After `.flatMap` do `.filter(str => str.startsWith('npm'))`

Comment: And is it possible to remove the `npm:` from each value after doing the filter?

Comment: Map afterwards and `str => str.slice(4)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your new comments, just to separate the logic out a little:

[Iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) to get a key/value pair (the value is the object), and then iterate over the files of each object. If there are any deps [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the "npm" ones, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that array and create a new one with the updated names.

Add that array to the `packages` array.

Finally [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the packages array, dedupe it by creating [a new Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from it, and then [spreading that back out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into an array as the value of the packages object you then add to the output object using the key.

```js
const data={"image-processing":{type:"lib",data:{files:[{file:"libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",hash:"62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d"},{file:"libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",hash:"a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",deps:["npm:gm","npm:mongodb"]}]}},"image-processing-2":{type:"lib",data:{files:[{file:"libs/photography/processing/.babelrc",hash:"62d50f586b2880f9d58ca4e9a84914c6a0d4936d",deps:["npm:gm","npm:faker"]},{file:"libs/photography/processing/src/lib/processing.ts",hash:"a285d3554f264cc60f35bef6180298badb0478d1",deps:["npm:gm","npm:mongodb"]}]}}};
// Output object
const out = {};

// Iterate over the object entries
for (const [key, obj] of Object.entries(data)) {
  
  // Destructure the type, and the files
  // array from each object
  const { type, data: { files } } = obj;
  
  const packages = [];

  // Iterate over each `files` array
  for (const file of files) {

    if (file.deps) {
      
      // `filter` out the "npm" names, and
      // then `map` over that array to update the names
      const list = file.deps
        .filter(dep => dep.startsWith('npm:'))
        .map(dep => dep.replace('npm:', ''));

      // Bang that completed array into `packages`
      packages.push(list);
    
    }

  }

  // Finally create a new key/value on the output
  // object by setting the value as an object
  // with `type`, and the flattened, deduped packages array
  out[key] = {
    type,
    packages: [...new Set(packages.flat())]
  };

}

console.log(out);
```